# Как отображать конкретную строку DataGrid в зависимости от выбранного элемента ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Создаю приложение с MVVM на wpf, возникла трудность. Нужно, чтобы при выборе элемента ListBox в DataGrid-е отображалась информация только о выбранном элементе. Сейчас все хорошо работает, но в DataGrid-е содержится информация о всех объектах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно, чтобы в DataGrid-е выводился только один ряд, в зависимости от выбранного элемента:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Model:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int x, y, z;
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set
        {
            x = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("X");
        }
    }
    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set
        {
            y = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Y");
        }
    }
    public int Z
    {
        get { return z; }
        set
        {
            z = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Z");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Models { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Models = new ObservableCollection<Model>
        {
            new Model{Name="First", X=1, Y=1, Z = 1},
            new Model{Name="Second", X=2, Y=2, Z = 2 },
            new Model{Name="Third", X=3, Y=3, Z = 3 },
        };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox x:Name="list1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Models}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Models}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="X" Binding="{Binding X}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y" Binding="{Binding Y}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Z" Binding="{Binding Z}" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Тут несколько вариантов. 1. Привязать у `ListBox` свойство `ItemSelected`, которое отдаст вам выбранный `Model` и при его изменение формировать коллекцию, которая создана специально для `DataGrid` эти самые объекты. Все, выбралось новое значение, в свойство оно занеслось, свойство отредактировало коллекцию, `DataGrid` это принял. 2. Есть такая штука, называется `ICollectionView`, некая надслойка над основной коллекцией, которая имеет методы фильтрации, вот вам достаточно ее создать, привязать к ней `DataGrid`, написать фильтр, привязать `SelectedItem` и в случае обновления делать `Refresh();`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ фильтр у `CollectionView` профильтрует и список и таблицу одновременно.

Comment: @aepot Смотря как и к чему привязать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать конвертер и прибиндиться к текущему элементу списка через него.

**ItemToListConverter.cs**

```csharp
public class ItemToListConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => value != null ? new List<object> { value } : null;

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => null;
}
```

Добавить конвертер в ресурсы

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xaml
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ItemToListConverter x:Key="ItemToListConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

`IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` теперь не требуется, я убрал

**MainWindow.xaml**

```csharp
<ListBox x:Name="list1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="5">
                <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=list1, Converter={StaticResource ItemToListConverter}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="X" Binding="{Binding X}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y" Binding="{Binding Y}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Z" Binding="{Binding Z}" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image: item-to-list-converter]

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 5):

Допустим у нас есть такая разметка (2 контрола, которые должны вывести разную информацию).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding OriginCollection}"  >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding OriginCollection}" />
</Grid>
```

Нам надо в `DataGrid` (странно конечно, почему он) вывести выделенный объект из `ListBox`:

- Для начала нам нужен сам этот объект:

  - Делаем свойство

    ```
    public TestClass Selected { get; set; }
    ```
  - Привязываем `SelectedItem` у `ListBox`

    ```
    SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}"
    ```
- Далее нам нужно нечто, что будет фильтровать нам данные, для этой цели существует такая вещь, как `ICollectionView`:

  - Делаем свойство

    ```
    public ICollectionView SortedCollection { get; }
    ```
  - Инициализируем его (задав источником основную коллекцию)

    ```
    SortedCollection = new CollectionViewSource { Source = OriginCollection }.View;
    ```
  - Задаем фильтр, по которому будет эта коллекция нам выдавать значения (если объект равен выбранному)

    ```
    SortedCollection.Filter = item => item == Selected;
    ```
  - Вызываем у свойства `Selected` метод обновления коллекции:

    ```
    public TestClass Selected
    {
        get => selected;
        set
        {
            selected = value;
            SortedCollection.Refresh();
        }
    }
    ```

Собственно и все, осталось привязать `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SortedCollection}" />
```

[image: Result]

Без чего либо лишнего, за нас думает система, нам надо только сделать правильный фильтр и привязать, все.

Comment: Тоже крутой вариант. Эффективнее предложенного мной, если данных очень много. К тому же мой вариант обрабатывает только частный случай с текущим элементом, а здесь можно любой фильтр прикрутить.

Comment: Можете про TestClass дописать. Не совсем понятно.

Comment: @Tand Простой, любой класс, со свойствами внутри, ну либо любой другой тип. Так, как в вопросе нужна была таблица, то у меня было что-то по типу `public class TestClass { public int Id { get;} public string Name {get:}` (или `public record TestClass(int Id, string Name);`). Так что, тут, собственно, и дописывать нечего.