# WPF Binding List<XXX>

Tags: c#, wpf

Вот такая картина

```
   public class Config
    {
        public String Key { get; set; }

        public String ValueConfig { get; set; }
    }
    
    
    public class ConfigTemplates : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private String title;
            private List<Config> configs;
    
            public String Title
            {
                get => title;
                set
                {
                    title = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
                }
            }
            
            public List<Config> Configs
            {
                get => configs;
                set
                {
                    configs = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Configs));
                }
            }
    
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
            [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        
         public sealed class ApplicationViewModelContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
            {
                private ConfigTemplates selectedConfig;
        
                public ObservableCollection<ConfigTemplates> Configs { get; set; }
                            
                public ConfigTemplates SelectedConfig
                {
                    get => selectedConfig;
                    set
                    {
                        selectedConfig = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedConfig));
                    }
                }            
        
                public ApplicationViewModelContext()
                {                   
        
                    Configs = new ObservableCollection<ConfigTemplates>()
                    {
                        new ConfigTemplates()
                        {
                            Title = "XXX",
                            
                            Configs = new List<Config>()
                            {
                                new Config {Key = $"1", ValueConfig = $@"XXX1"},
                                new Config {Key = $"2", ValueConfig = $@"XXX2"},
                                new Config {Key = $"3", ValueConfig = $@"XXX3"}
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
        
                public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        
                [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
                private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
            
            
            <Grid>
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>   
              
                    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Configs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedConfig}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="5">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                    
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding SelectedConfig}">
                        <TextBlock Text="Selected Settings"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Title"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        
                        <-- НЕ работает --!>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Configs, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        
                    </StackPanel>
                    
                </Grid>
```

как можно вывести данные Configs

```
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Configs, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

То есть, слева отображается Title, при нажатии на него, справа должны отобразится данные из Configs .
Работает, Title отображается, но Configs отображаются не правильно.Как можно вывести `Key = $"1", ValueConfig = $@"XXX1"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень странный у вас какой то код. В нем у вас свойство `Title`, содержащий просто строку, а `Configs` это некий список несвязанных с `Title` объектов. Как вы их связывать собираетесь я не пойму. Ну либо вы нам не пойми что скинули, ибо судя по XAML вы привязываетесь к одному списку - `Confings`.  По поводу "Не правильно отображается" - а шаблон задать объекту?  Вот у вас два `ListBox`, в первом вы переопределили шаблон, выведя `Title`, а у второго кто будет?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Есть связь, класс `ConfigTemplates` содержит свойство Title и Configs. Соединяю я их через `ObservableCollection<ConfigTemplates> Configs` то есть Configs уже имеет и Title у которого есть список Configs. по сути мне нужно сделать что то типо  этого  `foreach (var config in Configs)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine($"{config.Title}");
                 foreach (var configConfig in config.Configs)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine($"{configConfig.Key}  - {configConfig.ValueConfig}");
                 }
            }` но в XAML

Comment: Ну тогда вам либо [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553), либо через `SelectedItem` выводить.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, такой способ я пробовал и он работает, но проблема в том что у одного Title-а может быть несколько разных Key и ValueConfig. На счёт SelectedItem попробую! Спасибо!

Comment: Вы не дали данные с которыми мы можем работать, как вы предлагаете нам тогда помочь вам? Сейчас вот узнается, что один `Title` имеет разные значения и где это в вопросе? Где там вообще что либо похожее на "правду"? Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в него все необходимое! По поводу "несколько значений"  - делайте [фильтр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1140841/220553), самый лучший вариант. Ну либо да, `SelectedItem`, если оно изменилось, то формируете новую коллекцию, найдя все, к чему относится `Title` (аля `Items = Configs.Where(x=>x.Title == Selected.Title);`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вот данные, вроде понятно `new ConfigTemplates()
                        {
                            Title = "XXX",
                            
                            Configs = new List<Config>()
                            {
                                new Config {Key = $"1", ValueConfig = $@"XXX1"},
                                new Config {Key = $"2", ValueConfig = $@"XXX2"},
                                new Config {Key = $"3", ValueConfig = $@"XXX3"}
                            }
                        }` за фильтр огромное спасибо, должно подойти!