# WPF Binding Привязка Dictionary с вложенным списком к listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

Возможно ли привязка Dictionary с внутренним списком ObservableCollection к элементу listbox ?
или это можно сделать проще. В данном примере привязки не корректны.

---

Пояснение: 1)Listbox x:Name="List_dir": отвечает за показ ключей словаря;
2)ListView x:Name="List_dir2" Отвечает за вывод списка(ObservableCollection) по ключу.

Предполагаемый функционал: Создание ключей; Добавление данных в существующий список по ключу; Удаление данных из списка по ключу\Изменение данных из списка по ключу; Поиск ключей в Listbox x:Name="List_dir"

```
   public class mySelectedItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public mySelectedItem(string name, string password,string description)
        {
            Name = name;
            Password = password;
            Description = description;
        }
        
    }

    Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<mySelectedItem>> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<mySelectedItem>>();
   
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        dict1.Add("f1", new ObservableCollection<mySelectedItem>());
        dict1["f1"].Add(new mySelectedItem("log1","pas1","desc1"));
        dict1["f1"].Add(new mySelectedItem("log2","pas2","desc2"));
    }
```

XAML:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="List_dir" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" Margin="-1,-1,0,-1" ItemsSource="{Binding dict1}" BorderBrush="White" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="icon/f1.png" MaxWidth="20" MaxHeight="20" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" FontSize="14"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

<ListView x:Name="List2_dir" ItemsSource="{Binding Asset.dict1.Values}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Red">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu">
                    <MenuItem x:Name="menuItem_CopyUsername" Click="menuItem_CopyUsername_Click" Header="Copy Username">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="icon/def.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="menuItem_CopyPassword" Click="menuItem_CopyPassword_Click" Header="Copy Password">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="icon/def.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="menuItem_DeleteCreds" Click="menuItem_DeleteCreds_Click" Header="Delete">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="icon/def.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ItemContextMenu}" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true">
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Логин" Width="150"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Password}" Header="Пароль" Width="150"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}" Header="Описание" Width="200"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Скриншот программы что должно получиться:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не объяснили, что именно вам нужно, но словарь вам точно здесь не нужен. `Суть: При выборе itema` - это не суть, это хотелка. Суть - это то, зачем все это нужно. И именно ее в вашем вопросе не хватает, чтобы понять, как это можно реализовать. Что содержит ключ словаря? Вангую, что тоже самое, что и свойство `Name`? Если так, то у вас ошибка проектирования - данные не должны дублироваться. Если нет, то расскажите, что к чему: что делает или должен делать ваш код/приложение?

Comment: @aepot Добавил скриншот, может так станет немного понятнее

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [При помощи каких средств можно сделать отображение сообщений как в outlook?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816132/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-outlook)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отображать конкретную строку DataGrid в зависимости от выбранного элемента ListBox?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140779/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-datagrid-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-l)

Comment: @aepot не совсем то что там реализовано. Тут вложенный список в который можно по ключу добавлять элементы, а там этого нету

Comment: А зачем вам здесь ключ? Вы знаете, чем `ObservableCollection` от `List` отличается?

Comment: @aepot а каким образом можно обойтись без ключа, когда нам нужно добавить не 1 строчку с данными. Вот вы прислали пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140779/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-datagrid-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-l

Comment: Там реализовано просто, я так сделал. Но нет идей как можно добавить не 1 строчку с логином\паролем\описанием

Comment: @EvgeniyZ То есть заместо словаря можно так?   ```public ObservableCollection<KeyValueCollection> Models { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<KeyValueCollection>();```

Comment: ```public class KeyValueCollection
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public ObservableCollection<Model> Data_list { get; set; }
            public KeyValueCollection()
            {
                Data_list = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
            }
           
        }```

Comment: и далее мы можем добавлять\создавать и т.д. Но как привязать все это дело в wpf.```Models.Add(new KeyValueCollection { Name = "asdfg" });
            var item = Models.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "asdfg");
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.Data_list.Add(new Model { Name = "Folder", Login = "Folder", Password = "Folder", Description = "Folder" });
            }```

Comment: Я же вам дал ссылку на дубликат, где подробно описывается то, что вы хотите. По сути, без разницы что за тип будете вы использовать, за исключением только того, что `ObservableCollection` реализует `INotifyCollectionChanged`, что позволяет автоматически, без вашего участия, обновить интерфейс при добавлении/удалении объекта.

Comment: `Но как привязать все это дело` - опять же, ссылка выше, где вы можете увидеть, что у `ListBox` надо задать `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`, это позволит синхронизировать другие элементы с тем, что выбрано в нем, ну и соотстветственно его надо привязать (`ItemsSource = "{Binding dict1}"` (или в случае вашего комментария `ItemsSource = "{Binding Models}"`), далее ему надо переопределить `ListBox.ItemTemplate`, задав там нужный вид отображения (в случае словаря будет `{Binding Key}`, а в случае коллекции `{Binding Name}`).

Comment: Теперь остается `ListView`, который мы привязываем таким образом 
в случае словаря: `ItemsSource = "{Binding dict1/Value}"`, в случае коллекции: `ItemsSource = "{Binding dict1/Data_list}"`. Обратите внимание на `/`, через нее какраз и задается дальше свойство для синхронизации, то есть левая часть должна быть идентична той, что вы указывали у `ListBox`, а правая должна указывать на свойство для привязки (в вашем случае коллекция). Все, вот вы и привязали в пару строк кода все данные, вид только не забудьте указать для `ListView` нужный. Если что не ясно, то читайте дубликат, внимательней!