# Как в C# сделать аналогичный слушатель как в Java для зависимости между ComboBOX

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в C# сделать аналогичный слушатель, как в JavaFX для зависимости между ComboBOX, пример ниже как делал в JavaFX

```
 private String [] Region_Box_Arr = {"Санкт-Петербург", "Москва", "Алтайский край"};
    private String [] SPB = {"Санкт-Петербург"};
    private String [] MSK = {"Москва"};
    private String [] AltKr = {"Барнаул", "Бийск", "Рубцовск", "Новоалтайск", "Заринск", "Камень-на-Оби", "Славгород", "Алейск"};
    @FXML
    void initialize(){}
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        Region_Box.getItems().addAll(Region_Box_Arr);
        Region_Box.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldval, newVal)->
        {State_Box.getItems().clear();
        if (newVal == null) {
        State_Box.setDisable(true);}
        else if ("Санкт-Петербург".equals(newVal)){
        State_Box.getItems().addAll(SPB); }
        else if ("Москва".equals(newVal)) {
        State_Box.getItems().addAll(MSK); }
        else и т д
```

Comment: В WPF не принято напрямую лезть к контролам без важной причины. Для этого есть биндинги.

Comment: Как тогда сделать зависимые выпадающие списки?

Comment: Все зависит от того, как вы храните все эти данные. Допустим, логично сделать класс "Регион", в котором будет коллекция городов, потом создать коллекцию самих регионов, и вот у вас уже связанные данные, ну а вывод их будет [таким](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553). Если вы связь не хотите делать, то вам нужно у первого бокса привязать `SelectedItem` и при его изменении менять привязанную коллекцию уже городов. Ну и третий вариант [фильтры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1140841/220553). Вариантов как видите уйма.