# Замена ItemsSource

Tags: c#, avalonia

Делаю фильтр по поиску

```
       var a1 = shetaviewModel.shetas.Where(x => GetPropertyValue(x, sd) != null);
       this.list1.ItemsSource = a1;
```

и все нормально работает до тех пор пока не произошла корректировка какой-либо строки .
После корректировки мне надо сделать

```
    this.list1.Columns[sortcolumn].Sort(System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

и фильтр пропал , возвращается нефильтрованная таблица . Как бы это обойти .

Comment: Одно слово - Привязка (и я вам про него вроде как говорил). Ну не пишут в WPF и далее код вот так топорно, в стиле WinForms, да даже в WinForms уже давно не пишут так. UI в одном месте, данные в другом, все, точка, никак иначе, никаких `list1.ItemsSource = a1`. Самый простой пример привязки: В конструкторе окна `DataContext = this;`, в этом-же классе окна делаете публичное свойство нужного типа, например текст `public string SomeText {get;} = "Некий текст";`, далее в XAML пишете `<TextBlock Text = "{Binding SomeText}" />`, все, на экране у вас `Некий текст`. Сложно? Не думаю...

Comment: Далее развиваете эту тему, отделяете UI от данных, вынося свойство в отдельный класс, тогда уже не `= this`, а `= new НекийКласс();`. Ну и в итоге приходите к [такому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1140841/220553), где у вас есть данные, которые обернуты в `ICollectionView`, который уже и привязывается к вашему `list1`. Ну а самому `ICollectionView` задаете уже хоть фильтр, хоть сортировку. То, что вы сейчас делаете - это вы сами себе палки в колеса пихаете, ибо вместо того, чтоб позволить проекту помогать вам, вы берете всю ответственность на себя, зачем - не понятно..

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , я полностью с вами согласен и кстати у меня так и сделано только я не конечный продукт пишу и нет никакого смысла писать совсем правильно то что я выкину поняв как оно работает . Тут в коллекциях вроде  нет никаких view вот и получается что надо заменять ItemsSource на фильтрованную выборку а она слетает. Тогда надо иметь сразу два комплекта выборок исходный не изменяемый и фильтрованный подключаемый или можно сделать по другому ? у меня есть большие обьемы и хранить две копии как-то не хочется а подход хочу универсальный .

Comment: ` у меня так и сделано` - я этого не вижу. Я вижу что вы имеете проблему скорей всего из-за того, что вы именно так не делаете, ибо имея привязки, о всяких `ItemsSource` забывается вовсе. `нет никакого смысла` - использовать молоток для варки супа, или всеж половник? Зачем использовать то, что положено, если через пару часов будет съедено, вот ваша логика. Я вам не говорю писать прям идеально, я вам говорю, чтоб вы писали как положено, криво, косо, без разницы, но с привязками. `или можно сделать по другому` - я вам уже сказал как делать, там не две коллекции, а обертка одной над другой.

Comment: `у меня есть большие обьемы` - тогда такое надо делать на уровне базы, получать уже из нее отфильтрованный кусок данных, а не грузить все на клиента и сортировать там. Ваш вопрос сейчас про клиентскую фильтрацию, ну а за нее отвечает `ICollectionView`, где вы на лету можете ставить любой фильтр и любую сортировку, чего **автоматически** подтянет UI и отобразит это как надо.

Comment: А можно тупой вопрос ? где находится ICollectionView я не видел такой . На счет базы нет , лучше загрузить сразу 100 000 строк чем загружать часто по 1000 строк для поиска ИВАНОВА и потом там должны видеть всю базу для поиска "глазами"   .

Comment: `где находится` - Это уже спрашивайте у создателей авалонии, ибо это стандартный компонент WPF, на котором они и основывали свой проект, видать вынесли в отдельную библиотеку, ищите, должен быть либо он, либо аналог. `для поиска ИВАНОВА` - что мешает взять из базы всех таких пользователей и отобразить только их? На клиенте должны быть **только** важные данные, не более. Если вы грузите туда 100к строк ради лишь поиска **на клиенте**, чтож, это печально...

Comment: Ну зато сервер и сеть мне благодарны а сервер так прямо жизнью мне обязан . А в авалонии нет такой коллекции , была бы и вопроса бы небыло . Есть еще один . Как мне вытащить имя прибинденного обьекта из DataGridTextColumn , не могу найти .

Comment: Сервер на то и сервер, чтоб обрабатывать огромные объемы данных моментально, а вот пару десятков мб, а то даже и гб на клиенте с его условно 4гб RAM и медленным процессором, вот кто вам точно не скажет спасибо за такой "подгон"... Откройте к примеру любой сайт с динамической прокруткой, нажмите F12 в браузере и начните листать страницу, увидите, что постоянно на сервер идет отправка запроса для получения следующих данных, в итоге клиент имеет только то, что ему нужно на данный момент, а не 100к лишних данных лишь чтоб найти "Иванова"...

Comment: `ICollectionView` в авалонии походу обернули в `DataGridCollectionView`, действует судя по документации, аналогично, можете взять ее. `Как мне вытащить имя прибинденного обьекта` - не работайте с UI, работайте с данными. У вас есть привязанная коллекция - вот из нее и берите все, что хотите. Нужно то, что выделено, создайте отдельно публичное свойство и привяжите его к условному `SelectedItem`, будете всегда иметь в данном свойстве то, что сейчас выделено.

Comment: Да про DataGridCollectionView я уже увидел , спасибо за наводку сейчас буду копать в эту сторону . А из SelectedItem как вытащить одно поле ? я могу вытащить всю структура со всеми полями а какое из них прибиндено к нужной колонке по моему только из биндинга можно вытащить . У меня поиск делается по сортированному столбику .

Comment: Одна строка = 1 объект конкретного класса, это стандарт заполнения всяких DataGrid. Столбец = конкретное свойство данного класса. Условно `class User { public int Id {get;set;} public string Name {get; set;} }` ... `public List<User> Users {get;} = new {new User { Id = 1, Name = "Вася" }}; public User SelectedUser {get;set;}` ... `<DataGrid ItemsSource = "{Binding Users}" SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedUser}" />`, данный код выведет на экран одного пользователя, у которого будет 2 колонки, ну а при выделении, в `SelectedUser` будет сам класс, из которого и получайте данные.

Comment: Условный поиск в таком случае будет к примеру такой: `var result = Users.Where(x=>x.Name == "Вася");`, ну а в случае с фильтрацией (если ее настроили), там будет что-то по типу `Filter = user => user.Name == "Вася";` Ну, то есть простая работа **с классами**, а не с UI.

Comment: Извиняюсь если надоел , мне надо узнать к примеру что ко второй колонке прибинден ID При событии сортировки я могу запомнить номер сортируемой колонки sortcolumn = e.Column.DisplayIndex; а вытащить слово ID как ?

Comment: Вы меня не хотите походу понимать. Еще раз повторю, вы должны работать **с данными**, а не с UI. "Слово ID" - это UI часть, а не данные. Данные в свою очередь - это все, что относится к условному "человеку" (если разбираем мой пример). Аналогично и "Колонка", "Столбец", "Строка", и так далее - это все UI, которые вам попросту не нужны, ибо вы должны работать с привязанными **данными**.

Comment: Да вроде хочу понять но не получается . Вот вы пишете  Filter = user => user.Name == "Вася"; так не пойдет потому что данные отсортированы вовсе не по столбику Name а по столбику где ID и мой поиск делается так opens.Shet = shetaviewModel.shetas.First(x => GetPropertyValue(x, sd) != null); }  где в SD хранится имя или name или id и дальше GetPropertyValue который и отвечает за фильтрацию а SD я заполняю так string? sd = this.list1.Columns[sortcolumn].Tag?.ToString(); откуда видно что я это имя пришу в колонке еще и в tag потому что из биндинга вытащить не умею . Ладно спасибо за помощь .

Comment: Вы пробовали реализовать то, о чем я говорю? Еще раз повторю, вы меня не слышите. Я вам о привязках и работе с данными, где прям жирным выделяю "Вы не должны работать с UI", но вы уперто пытаетесь получить UI данные, упорно работаете с UI (`list1.Columns`), вместо того, чтоб просто пойти и сделать. Я ведь вам даже ссылку кидал с подробнейшим примером, но нет, мы уже с вами битый час говорим об одном....

Comment: Хорошо , наверно я не догоняю , ну вопрос . Допустим у вас есть модель из трех полей но в view вы не знаете как они располагаются , вы можете написать поиск по любому из трех столбиков в зависимости от того какой  столбик пользователь отсортирует ? можно на пальцах обьяснить направление ?